# Redux, React-Redux accessing variable from one page to next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm defining a variable in Page1 and would like to access it in Page2 and then when clicking back to Page1 retrieve the same variable

So far, the variable is set on Page1 but cannot be retrieved on Page2

index.js

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import variableReducer from './reducers'

const store = createStore(
    variableReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
)

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
)


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

actions/index.js

```
export const SET_MY_VARIABLE = 'SET_MY_VARIABLE'

export const setMyVariable =  myVariable => ({
    type: SET_MY_VARIABLE,
    payload: {myVariable}
})
```

reducers/index.js

```
import {SET_MY_VARIABLE} from '../actions'

const initialState = {
    myVariable: ''
}

const variableReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_MY_VARIABLE:
            return {
                ...state,
                myVariable: action.payload.myVariable
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default variableReducer
```

components/Page1.js

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import {connect, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import {setMyVariable} from '../actions'

const Page1 = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(setMyVariable(5000))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            Setting variable<br />
            <a href="/page2">Go to page 2</a>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapState = state => {

    return {
        myVariable: state.myVariable
    }
}

export default connect(mapState)(Page1)
```

components/Page2.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

const Page2 = (props) => {

    const {myVariable} = props
    console.log('props: ', props)

    return (
        <div>
            Variable: {myVariable}
        </div>
    )
}

const mapState = state => {
    console.log('map2 ', state.myVariable)
    return {
        myVariable: state.myVariable
    }
}

export default connect(mapState)(Page2)
```

I should be able to set variables to the store in one component and access them throughout the entire App. Instead, I'm not able to retrieve them

Comment: Do you have Redux dev tools installed in your browser and do you see the state change happen?

Comment: Yes I have dev tools installed and I see the state variable being set but 'undefined' on second page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the answer to my problem. I needed to change the `<a href` tag to a `<Link>` from react-router-dom in the Page1 component. The `<a href` was causing a complete reload of all JS and losing state. Here's the corrected component:

components/Page1.js

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import {connect, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import {setMyVariable} from '../actions'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const Page1 = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
       dispatch(setMyVariable(5000))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            Variable: {myVariable}<br />
            <Link to="/page2">Go to page 2</Link>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapState = state => {
    return {
        myVariable: state.myVariable
    }
}

export default connect(mapState)(Page1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `action.payload.myVariable` use `action.payload` in your reducer/index.js

Comment: I tried this and still get nothing
```
{history: {…}, location: {…}, match: {…}, staticContext: undefined, myVariable: "", …}
dispatch: ƒ ()
history: {length: 2, action: "POP", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}
location: {pathname: "/page2", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined}
match: {path: "/page2", url: "/page2", isExact: true, params: {…}}
myVariable: ""
staticContext: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Page1 has to be connected to the store? I know Page2 does. Can I just access the "myVariable" from props? Or do I have to create an action like -> GET_MY_VARIABLE and dispatch?

Comment: Maybe try to remove the brackets (`{}`) in the `actions/index.js` at the payload

Comment: No that's not it. I'm sure there's someone out there that knows what's happening here. This is a pretty basic example.

Comment: Is it possible that just using an `<a href>` link is causing this problem? In other words, should I be using a router link and passing props like so `<Page2 props={props} />`?

Comment: Come on people, there must be someone out there that can help me with this simple question. What am I missing that I cannot access the variable in the second page? Please.